# When installing Ubuntu I didn't know the passwords wouldn't show so I just kept hitting random keys. Now I don't know the password

Tags: boot, software-installation, password

this is my first Ubuntu - Linux installation.
I didn't know the password field would be invisible so I kept hitting random keys, and I'm guessing I also hit Enter twice because I received an error: Passwords don't match, try again? I pressed Y, but the process of installation kept going and I couldn't type the password I wanted to.

I've checked how to remove or change the password but I can't access recovery mode since my laptops' screen is dead (i use a monitor instead). I have tried holding shift down like 100000 times but I can't access recovery mode, plus the computer boots pretty fast so it makes it even harder.

How can I solve this issue?

I installed Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, Windows version is the latest one (2004). I enabled the "second screen only" option so my laptops screen won't turn on, but when booting it still does. It turns off once the Windows login screen is shown and from then I can use my monitor. Just in case, I use a Dell Latitude E7240. 
If Kernel version is useful: Linux 4.4.0-19041-Microsoft.
I really don't know anything about Linux and Ubuntu, just wanted to have it installed and after that I had planned to do some research, but it seems like I had to be done before installation.

Comment: You haven't said what OS/release you are using (just Ubuntu, not the release, or if server, desktop, Core etc).  On many laptops there are fn keys (laptop specific) that allow you to mirror internal/external display, turn one or both off etc which is usually easiest to bypass dead display.

Comment: @guiverc I installed Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. I'm on the latest windows (version 2004). I used Fn F8 to use the second screen only option on my Dell Latitude E7240, but nothing shows up until the Windows login screen is shown.

Comment: Reset password : https://askubuntu.com/q/24006/77093

Comment: Found a way to solve it, thank you all for trying to help me.

Answer (score 0):

Had to do this:

1. I opened up Command Prompt.
2. Changed dir: `cd C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps`. If you open that folder (you can do Windows + R) and find `ubuntu.exe`, it should work.
3. Logged onto root user: `ubuntu config --default-user root`. Personally it didn't require a password or something.
4. Start Ubuntu in that same cmd: `ubuntu`
5. Change password: `passwd username`. It shouldn't require the current password if you logged in as the root user.
6. And I proceeded to uninstall Ubuntu before running into any other issue. I need to do research BEFORE installing it, not after. Should learn at least the basics before diving into this new "world".